# How to sort object attributes

Tags: python, oop, sorting

I have an object roughly like so:

```
class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self, finger_names, finger_lengths, nail_sizes):
        self.finger_names = finger_names
        self.finger_lengths = finger_lengths
        self.nail_sizes = nail_sizes

   def _sort_by_finger_lengths(self):
        ????
```

`finger_names`, `finger_lengths` and `nail_sizes` are all either equally long lists or empty (for example, if the person hasn't measured their `nail_sizes` yet). The goal is to sort the attributes of the object by finger_lengths. So if you start with a Hand object where the lists are ordered by left-to-right names (pinky, ring, middle, pointer, thumb), you end up with a Hand object with all attributes sorted by finger_lengths.

Like so:

```
finger_names = [pinky, thumb, pointer, ring, middle]
finger_lengths = [6, 7, 12, 13, 15]
nail_sizes = []
```

**EDITED TO ADD**: Hand is just an example class. The real code has good reasons for having lists for each attribute.

Comment: I'd be really interested in a picture of the hand with the given finger lengths...

Comment: Your data structure is wrong. You need to have a single list, each item of which has 3 attributes, fingerName, fingerLength and nailSize. Then when you sort, all the associated attributes are kept together. Or you have a dict with fingerName as the key. But keep all the attributes for one finger together.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're right - this is just an example though. My real data is more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach is to do this:

```
>>> finger_names, finger_lengths
(('pointer', 'ring', 'pinky', 'middle', 'thumb'), (12, 13, 6, 15, 7))
>>> s_tuples = sorted(zip(finger_names, finger_lengths), key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> finger_names, finger_lengths = zip(*s_tuples)
>>> finger_names, finger_lengths
(('pinky', 'thumb', 'pointer', 'ring', 'middle'), (6, 7, 12, 13, 15))
```

However, [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9447958/577088) is right that you should probably link these up in a data structure, instead of depending on their order to associate them.

The above strategy (using `key`) still works in that case, but you don't need to use `zip(*s_tuples)` to disassociate them.

On the other hand, if you want to disassociate them, there's a one-liner solution that I forgot about before.

```
finger_lengths, finger_names = zip(*sorted(zip(finger_lengths, finger_names)))
```

Or, if you want to sort in place, saving one copy operation:

```
s_tuples = zip(finger_lengths, finger_names)
s_tuples.sort()
finger_lengths, finger_names = zip(*temp)
```

Answer (score 3):

Any number of people can tell you how to do this, but it seems fragile.  Why not make a `Finger` class and save yourself some sanity?

```
class Finger(object):
  PINKY = 0
  RING = 1
  MIDDLE = 2
  INDEX = 3
  THUMB = 4

  def __init__ (self, type):
    self.type = type
    self.length = None
    self.nail_size = None

  def __lt__ (self, other):
    return self.length < other.length

f = Finger(Finger.PINKY)
f.length = 6
```

This is both easy to sort in either direction, and you don't have to worry about misalignment of which fingers have reported lengths and which don't.

Comment: Sorry - should have made it clear this is just an example class. Real code is trickier.

Comment: @mlissner: It's hard to judge how one should do this with example code that apparently isn't actually like the real code.. :-)  I would be particularly interested in any class that had a "good reason" to have equally dimensioned but separate lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use single list with tuples of all three attributes to keep them together during sorting. A simple way to do this with your sort code using the existing data structures is to use `zip` to combine and unpack them like so

```
l = zip(finger_lengths, finger_names, nail_sizes)
l.sort()
finger_lengths, finger_names, nail_sizes = zip(*l)
```

This doesn't work if your nail sizes is empty though, so even if there's nothing you should populate it with zeroes maybe like `nail_sizes = [0] * 5`. If you want to keep the data structures as separate lists I suggest doing it like this. Otherwise if you don't mind reorganizing it to be more object oriented, it might be better to do as Nick says and make a finger class.